# How to set an existing field as a primary key in spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

When I am writing the data of a spark dataframe into SQL DB by using JDBC connector. It is overwritting the properties of the table.

So, i want to set the keyfield in spark dataframe before writing the data.

```py
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2};user={3};password={4};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false; hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase, JDBCusername, JDBCpassword)

newSchema_Product_names = [StructField('product__code',StringType(), False),                              
                               StructField('product__names__lang_code',StringType(),False),
                               StructField('product__names__name',StringType(),True),
                               StructField('product__country__code',StringType(),True),
                               StructField('product__country__name',StringType(),True)
                              ]

Product_names1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Product_names_new,StructType(newSchema_Product_names))
Product_names1.write.mode("overwrite").jdbc(url, "product_names")
```

Before:

[image: SQL TABLE]
After:

[image: SQL TABLE after running the code]

Comment: Unclear what u r asking.

Comment: My current key fields of sql table are product__code, product__names__lang_code. When i run the above code it is overwriting the sql table properties(Removing the key fields).

Comment: In the external database schema I presume you mean?

Comment: I have added the snippets of SQL table before and after running the code. Please have a look and suggest me how to proceed.

Comment: If possible i want to set existing fields(product__code, product__names__lang_code) as index/key while creating a spark dataframe.

So, when i am writing data to sql db using jdbc i will achieve the primary keys

Comment: Not sure, overwrite means clear and redo. maybe createTableOptions can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52762840/6664872).

Comment: @cronoik 
i have tried earlier by using the same method you suggested
`Product_names1.write.option("truncate", "true").jdbc(url, "product_names", mode = "overwrite") ` 

but i am facing the below error:

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 20, 172.20.4.133, executor 0): java.sql.BatchUpdateException: String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: That means your fields are not big enough to hold your data. Some values of your dataframe exceed the allowed length of your database schema (e.g. nvarchar(5) but one dataframe value has a length of 6).

Answer (score 0):

@cronoik yes its correct. I thought JDBC connector is not supporting truncate option. But after changing the size of the fields, it worked for me.